# Probability outcome $0$? Post measurement state?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, probability

Does anyone know how to solve this exercise? Here is the question:

> Let $|\psi\rangle$ be an arbitrary pure $n$-qubit state, i.e.
> $$|\psi\rangle=\sum_{x_1,\ldots,x_n=0,1}\alpha_{x_1\cdots x_n}|x_1\cdots x_n\rangle, \sum_{x_1,\ldots,x_n=0,1}|\alpha_{x_1\cdots x_n}|^2=1.$$
> What is the probability of obtaining the outcome $0$ on a measurement in the computational basis on the first qubit?  Conditioned on this outcome, what would be the post-measurement state of the $n$-qubit system and the corresponding reduced state for the last $n-1$ qubits?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE.  Can you edit the question to clarify where is this question from?  And also, edit the question to indicate what have you tried, and where are you having difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When measuring $x_1$, the state will collapse to a superposition of states that contain only states where $x_1=0$.

Since it still has to be normalized, (sum of all $|\alpha|^2$ should still be 1), there is a bit different expression.

So, the probability will be:

$$P(x_1=0) = \sum_{x_1=0}|\alpha_{x_1\cdots x_n}|^2$$

And the new state after collapsing to the state that $x_1=0$:

$$|\psi'\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{x_1=0;x_2,\ldots,x_n=0,1}|\alpha_{x_1\cdots x_n}|^2}}
\sum_{x_1=0;x_2,\ldots,x_n=0,1}\alpha_{x_1\cdots x_n}|0,x_2\cdots x_n\rangle$$

You can use the following explanation too: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Quantum_Mechanics_III_(Chong)/03%3A_Quantum_Entanglement/3.02%3A_Partial_Measurements